# Browsers block redirection to chrome extension application

Tags: rest, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

in chrome extension application it has a url like chrome-extension://lcoibdhlihchjibnocnoofbfobniiofp/index.html

and it request to server to authenticate using SNS Oauth

Flow looks like these

**chrome extension -> API server -> google -> API server(callback) -> chrome extension (redirect to)**

the situation is
if browser keeps google oauth session it works well
[image]

initiator accounts.google.com request to API server using **callback** endpoint
and it redirects to chrome extension well

but
**if browser doesn't keep session** so i must enter password to authenticate browser blocks redirection
[image]
[image]

[image]

I have no idea where to check to fix the issue.

#### diff

i got new difference between two situation

- the one Oauth session is not kept
  [image]
- the other Oauth session is kept
  [image]

could possibly initiator matter ?

Comment: Declare this callback page in web_accessible_resources.

Comment: it works you save my time.